# How to check whether a journal is still listed in Scopus?

Tags: scopus

In the time when I submitted a paper to a journal " Research Journal of Applied Sciences, Engineering and Technology", ISSN:  2040-7459, they indicated in their website that the journal is indexed in scopus but now is not, so i checked scimagojr.com for information and i found that the Coverage is: 2009-2014.

How do you check whether a journal is still listed in scopus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[UPDATE : 2018]**

*Not sure if the solution i am proposing existed when the question was asked, but just for the sake of update :*

I guess the easiest way to check if a journal is indexed in Scopus or not is by using their search engine, you can search by ISSN or name of the journal.

Here is a link where i search for the journal you are looking for :

.    [Search request in Scopus of the ISSN : 2040-7459](https://www.scopus.com/sources?sortField=metric&metricName=RP&sortDirection=ASC&offset=1&displayAll=false&sortPerformedState=f&origin=sourceSearch&sortDirectionMOne=DESC&sortDirectionMTwo=DESC&sortDirectionMThree=&metricDisplayIndex=1&scint=1&menu=search&tablin=&searchWithinResultsDefault=t&searchString=&searchOA=&typeFilter=d_j_p_k&subscriptionFilter=s_u&filterActTriggered=f&tabName=searchSources&searchTerms=20407459&searchTermsSubmit=&searchType=issn)

Answer (score 4):

The [entry for this journal](https://www.scopus.com/source/sourceInfo.uri?sourceId=19700187706) in Scopus lists "from 2009 to 2015" - it records 307 papers from 2015. The last issue they have indexed is vol. 10 issue 12, and they have not as yet indexed any 2016 papers.

The "to 2015" description seems to be standard for currently indexed journals; for example, [*Nature*](https://www.scopus.com/source/sourceInfo.uri?sourceId=21206) is listed as "1869 to 2015" despite being very much still alive. It doesn't automatically mean the journal has stopped being indexed - but the fact that Scopus does not list any 2016 papers yet does seem to suggest that it has stopped being indexed.

Note that Maxwell appears on Beall's list of [potentially predatory publishers](https://scholarlyoa.com/publishers/); while there are [many caveats](https://scholarlykitchen.sspnet.org/2013/12/16/parting-company-with-jeffrey-beall/) about Beall's work, it's certainly something to take note of.

Answer (score 3):

Scopus provide a spreadsheet of journals which they index, or have indexed in the past. It is linked from [this page](http://blog.scopus.com/posts/titles-indexed-in-scopus-check-before-you-publish). I have downloaded the spreadsheet, and in your case, the journal is specifically highlighted as no longer being indexed as they "do not meet the Scopus quality criteria anymore and therefore Scopus discontinued the forward capturing". However, if your paper was published in the range of time that the journal was indexed (2009-2015 according to the same spreadsheet), then it will still be in Scopus. You can confirm this by searching for it in the index.

The same Scopus page indicates that if you cannot find a journal in that spreadsheet, you can try searching Scopus for the name of the journal to see if any recent material has been indexed. As a last resort, you can contact Scopus.